# Where is the correct place to put google play's age group targeting code in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, targeting

I am trying to make my app available for people of all ages and there for need to add code that complies with google play's families policy. https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6223431?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccode-sample-for-implementation-in-apps-for-everyone-including-children-and-families

This is the code that I have added to my app:

```
    RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
    .toBuilder()
    .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(
        RequestConfiguration.TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
    .setMaxAdContentRating(RequestConfiguration.MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
    .build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
```

and this is where I have placed my code within my app:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    
        RequestConfiguration requestConfiguration = MobileAds.getRequestConfiguration()
                .toBuilder()
                .setTagForChildDirectedTreatment(
                        RequestConfiguration.TAG_FOR_CHILD_DIRECTED_TREATMENT_TRUE)
                .setMaxAdContentRating(RequestConfiguration.MAX_AD_CONTENT_RATING_G)
                .build();
        MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(requestConfiguration);
    
    
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {}
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    
        InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
    
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.toString());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });
}
```

Could someone verify if this is the correct placement of the code in order for it to comply with google play's families policy as I am not familiar with this task and do not know how to test it out on where it works or not as there is no change in the app when running it on a device.